# How do I see what files are taking up the most space in unix?

Tags: unix

I have used `du -h` and `df -h`, but I cannot seem to determine what actual files are taking up space. When I remove the files `df -h` still says that the disk is full. Also when I delete the files based on `du -h`, the space for sda2 does not decrease.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              13G   12G     0 100% /
/dev/sda1             251M   21M  218M   9% /boot
tmpfs                1006M     0 1006M   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: This question is more for ServerFault. But i have experienced the same thing and i think some thing is wrong with the linux filesystem (i don't want to say bug but it looks like one). Reboot will do the trick.

Comment: How do I restart? I guess I have to be a su

Comment: @lord12, you really shouldn't need to reboot on Unix.  Unfortunately, the whole "reboot" mindset seems to have crept in from the Windows world.

Comment: @Eric Smith actually, what i described has nothign to do with "mindset." We had to restart productions Linux server because of that kind of reason, and it happend multiple times. Nothing could be written on that filesystem even we deleted many big files

Comment: @OpDeCirkel Well you have more experience with this problem, it's just surprising that one would have to reboot in order to "clear" this.

Comment: If there's a process with a (possibly nameless) file that it is writing to, then the space won't be released until the program closes the file.  (And a reboot will stop that program, thereby releasing the space.)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Interesting! If i remove file that some process still has open handle to it, is it such case? - If, yes this can happen very often with log files ... I thought that in that case the file will get recreated and filled up with 0x0 to the point the poceess continues to write

Comment: If you delete a file while a process has it open, then yes, the file can continue to grow, using space that you can't easily track (except as the difference between the space used by named files and the space reported as free by `df`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick for finding the big files (that have names) is usually `du -a`, often piped into `sort -n`.  This gives you the biggest files last (so it doesn't matter that the small files disappear off the top of the page).

You may have a process still running with a nameless file open that it is writing to when it gets the chance, that is eating up the space.  This could be a temporary file that it opened to store data, or it could be a log file that someone removed.  The space it uses won't show as free space, but neither will it show up as in use with `du -a` (or any other options) because there isn't a file name.  If you don't know which process it is, you could use a reboot to stop the process (all processes), thereby releasing the space.

Comment: perhaps you can find those _nameless_ guys with `sudo lsof`

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the `df` man page:

```
`--no-sync'
     Do not invoke the `sync' system call before getting any usage data.
     This may make `df' run significantly faster on systems with many
     disks, but on some systems (notably SunOS) the results may be
     slightly out of date.  This is the default.
```

Since this is the default, I'm guessing that you're getting a cached view of free space.

Answer (score 0):

use the below command for checking the disk space:

```
df -lh
```